# Best way to dismiss the keyboard in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextview

UITextView is multiline. So I can't use the DONE button to dismiss the keyboard. Now what's best practise? Add a navigation bar or toolbar on top and then put an DONE button in there?

Comment: I have similar problem. I have a save button on top and using resignFirstResponder, but it not works. It only remove focus from UITextView (not hiding the keyboard). Any Idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A button on top is common.

You have to ask yourself what the user can and want to do next.

- Are there more fields to be filled out. Then it would be a "next" (and/or "previous") button on the top
- Does the user just like to consider the input "done" and so does use the "back" button to go where he came from
- Is there another next view (and not other UITextFields in this view) then you may have a "Submit" button or something like this

Hope it helps

Comment: I have a save button on top. but resignFirstResponder not works. It only remove focus from UITextView (not hiding the keyboard)

Comment: How about you ask a new question and show the code you have so far.